# Argument of type '"contextPaneTitleText"' is not assignable to parameter of type 'keyof RemoteConfig'

Tags: typescript

I am using this

```js
 const contextPaneTitleText = useFeature("contextPaneTitleText").asString();
```

this is giving me error

> > Argument of type '"contextPaneTitleText"' is not assignable to parameter of type 'keyof RemoteConfig'

[error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kLFIe.png)

this is my useFeature file code

```js
import * as React from "react";
import { fetchAndActivate, getValue } from "firebase/remote-config";

import { remoteConfig } from "../../firebase";
import type { RemoteConfig } from "../../firebase";

type FeatureName = keyof RemoteConfig;

function useFeature(name: FeatureName) {
 async function fetchConfig() {
 await fetchAndActivate(remoteConfig);
}

React.useEffect(() => {
  void fetchConfig();
}, [name]);

 // reenable these to use different remote config settings for stage than for prod
 // const flagName = ENV === "stage" ? `stage_${name}` : name;
 // return getValue(remoteConfig, flagName);

  return getValue(remoteConfig, name);
} 

export { useFeature };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message suggests that the string `"contextPaneTitleText"` is not recognized as a valid key of the `RemoteConfig` type. This means that when you attempt to call `useFeature("contextPaneTitleText")`, TypeScript checks against the `RemoteConfig` type to ensure `"contextPaneTitleText"` is a defined property name within that type. If it's not found, TypeScript will raise the error you're seeing because it can't guarantee that `"contextPaneTitleText"` is a valid configuration key according to the type definitions you've provided.

Is `contextPaneTitleText` a Defined Key in the `RemoteConfig` type?

Comment: Thanks you.
`contextPaneTitleText` was not defined in `RemoteConfig `